# Error en : compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Emite este error al momento de añedir el paquete

**compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'**

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzmx.class
>
> [image: GRADLE]

Comment: Publica el contenido de tu archivo gradle de la aplicacion para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se puede crear un mix de versiones 
reorganice y deje en una sola version standar y funciono

**Compilo el APK sin problemas**

[image: Compilo el APK sin problemas]